# How to use pandas to assign values to newly added columns based on the original data？

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image: my picture]

As shown in the figure, there are different classifications of "VISCODE2" in the same "RID". The "BSXSYMNO" coding pair uses 29 empty columns. I want to represent the "BSXSYMNO" corresponding to the same "VISCODE2" with a line. In each empty column, the attribute used is coded by 1, and the others are coded by 0.
I used a dictionary to store the encoded values.

```py
ph_dict = {1:'AXNAUSEA', 2:'AXVOMIT', 3:'AXDIARRH', 4:'AXCONSTP',5:'AXABDOMN', 6:'AXSWEATN', 7:'AXDIZZY',
               8:'AXENERGY', 9:'AXDROWSY',10:'AXVISION',11:'AXHDACHE', 12:'AXDRYMTH', 13:'AXBREATH', 14:'AXCOUGH',
               15:'AXPALPIT', 16:'AXCHEST',17:'AXURNDIS', 18:'AXURNFRQ',19:'AXANKLE', 20:'AXMUSCLE', 21:'AXRASH',
               22:'AXINSOMN',23:'AXDPMOOD', 24:'AXCRYING', 25:'AXELMOOD', 26:'AXWANDER', 27:'AXFALL',28:'AXOTHER',
               29:'AXSPECIF',}
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    vis = row['VISCODE2']
    num = row['BSXSYMNO']
    if(0<num<=20):
        df2.loc[index,df2[ph_dict[num]]]=1
```

The result I want is shown below.
[image: my picturre2]

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: From sample data why is for `m72` returned `1`, for `m06` is `-4` ? It seems dependent of dict, but no such data in sample dict. Is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: The BSXSYMNO code corresponding to m06 is -4, indicating that the value in this row is missing, and the corresponding column values are all -4.

Comment: How I know `m72` is need processing by dict (I guees)?

Comment: The BSXSYMNO code (3, 7, 18, 20, 28) corresponding to m72 is the key in the dictionary, and the value in the dictionary is the column to be filled

Comment: So need processing all rows if positive `BSXSYMNO` ?

Comment: yes, but first need to deal with BSXSYMNO.

Comment: hmmm, My problem is  I have no your data. I have picture, which cannot be copied (check first link), then seems dictioanry not matched to data (in dictioanry no information about `m72`) so how answer should be created?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ueaa-u6A6Nx6Q4-R-ZS4RWTV6gqMCqPV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
ph_dict = {1:'AXNAUSEA', 2:'AXVOMIT', 3:'AXDIARRH', 4:'AXCONSTP',5:'AXABDOMN', 6:'AXSWEATN', 7:'AXDIZZY',
               8:'AXENERGY', 9:'AXDROWSY',10:'AXVISION',11:'AXHDACHE', 12:'AXDRYMTH', 13:'AXBREATH', 14:'AXCOUGH',
               15:'AXPALPIT', 16:'AXCHEST',17:'AXURNDIS', 18:'AXURNFRQ',19:'AXANKLE', 20:'AXMUSCLE', 21:'AXRASH',
               22:'AXINSOMN',23:'AXDPMOOD', 24:'AXCRYING', 25:'AXELMOOD', 26:'AXWANDER', 27:'AXFALL',28:'AXOTHER',
               29:'AXSPECIF'}
```

---

```
#need columns which are not filledn NaNs
need = ['Phase','RID','VISCODE2','BSXSYMNO']
df = pd.read_csv('RECDE.csv')
print (df.head(3))
   Phase  RID VISCODE2  BSXSYMNO  AXNAUSEA  AXVOMIT  AXDIARRH  AXCONSTP  \
0  ADNI1    2       bl      14.0       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN   
1  ADNI1    2       bl      18.0       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN   
2  ADNI1    2       bl      20.0       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN   

   AXABDOMN  AXSWEATN  ...  AXMUSCLE  AXRASH  AXINSOMN  AXDPMOOD  AXCRYING  \
0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
1       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   

   AXELMOOD  AXWANDER  AXFALL  AXOTHER  AXSPECIF  
0       NaN       NaN     NaN      NaN       NaN  
1       NaN       NaN     NaN      NaN       NaN  
2       NaN       NaN     NaN      NaN       NaN  

[3 rows x 33 columns]
```

---

```
#filled greater 0 and less or equal 20
mask = df['BSXSYMNO'].gt(0) & df['BSXSYMNO'].le(20)

#created indicator only for filtered BSXSYMNO column mapped by dict
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.loc[mask, 'BSXSYMNO'].map(ph_dict))
#repeated not matched rows
df2 = df.loc[~mask, ['BSXSYMNO']].reindex(['BSXSYMNO'] + df1.columns.tolist(), axis=1).ffill(axis=1).drop('BSXSYMNO', axis=1)
#joined together and added original columns
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=True).sort_index().join(df[need]).reindex(df.columns, axis=1, fill_value=0)
```

---

```
print (df.head(3))
   Phase  RID VISCODE2  BSXSYMNO  AXNAUSEA  AXVOMIT  AXDIARRH  AXCONSTP  \
0  ADNI1    2       bl      14.0       0.0      0.0       0.0       0.0   
1  ADNI1    2       bl      18.0       0.0      0.0       0.0       0.0   
2  ADNI1    2       bl      20.0       0.0      0.0       0.0       0.0   

   AXABDOMN  AXSWEATN  ...  AXMUSCLE  AXRASH  AXINSOMN  AXDPMOOD  AXCRYING  \
0       0.0       0.0  ...       0.0       0         0         0         0   
1       0.0       0.0  ...       0.0       0         0         0         0   
2       0.0       0.0  ...       1.0       0         0         0         0   

   AXELMOOD  AXWANDER  AXFALL  AXOTHER  AXSPECIF  
0         0         0       0        0         0  
1         0         0       0        0         0  
2         0         0       0        0         0  

[3 rows x 33 columns]
```